# Sites 10 Experience Space Extension - Example

Tags: experience-space

we have recently installed Sites 10 CME and I am trying to integrate some of the extensions in new UI.

Currently i am facing one issue. I need to show context menu tool bar item on component selection but

{currentNode} = UseContextExplorer();

above method returns the current folder but not the actual component selected.

can you please share some example to show the context menu items on component/page selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Tridion Sites 10 UX Update installed, the selected item(s) in the table can be accessed using the new useContentExplorerTable hook:

{ selection } = useContentExplorerTable();

The selection object includes both a set of item ids and an array of items currently selected.

The same API can be used by accessing the selection state in other views (i.e., Activities and Publishing) as well.

An example extension which illustrates the use of this API can be found here:

https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples/blob/main/sites-10-ux-update/content-explorer/copy-schema-item-ids-action-addon/copy-schema-item-ids-action/src/copySchemaItemIdsToClipboardAction/useCopySchemaItemIdsToClipboard.tsx

Answer (score 1):

We reviewed your request and unfortunately how to determine the selected item (or items) in the table, this is not currently supported in the 10.0 Extension API.

we are planning to have a UX update with some additional hotfix which we are planning to release soon.

I will update you once we get some update about the hotfix.

Hope it helps ! Wait for the update soon.

Comment: Sure, thanks for confirming!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to Tridion Stack Exchange , please refer to the sample [link](https://github.com/RWS/tridion-sites-extensions-examples/tree/main/content-explorer/simple-action-addon)

please share the code snippet so we can review and get back to you.

Comment: I wanted to show custom tool bar menu on component/ page selection . The menu should display only on component or page selection

Comment: I have referred rws github repo but it doesn't have any examples for above use case.

Comment: will review and get back to you